# Customising OpenSSL config file to make it work with both custom engine and TLS v1.0

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, ubuntu-20.04

I have already asked the question on ask ubuntu but it looks like the community doesn't know the answer

[How to configure curl (openssl) in order to make it work with custom engine and TLSv1.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335768/how-to-configure-curl-openssl-in-order-to-make-it-work-with-custom-engine-and)

I experimented with the `openssl.cnf` file and found out that I can make TLSv1.0 work by configuring the file like this:

```
#openssl_conf = openssl_def
openssl_conf = openssl_init

... (openssl default config)

#[openssl_def] 
#engines = engine_section 
 
#[engine_section] 
#gost = gost_section 
 
#[gost_section] 
#engine_id = gost 
#dynamic_path = /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1/gost.so
#default_algorithms = ALL 
#CRYPT_PARAMS = id-Gost28147-89-CryptoPro-A-ParamSet

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

It enabled curl to communicate over TLSv1.0

But I can't for the life of me configure it to enable both TLSv1.0 and the custom engine called GOST.

Could anyone suggest the right configuration please?

Comment: If it's not possible please let me know

Answer (score 0):

This works. https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/175005/cuando-trato-de-curl-un-sitio-web-me-da-error-ssl

Summary:

1. Create file: ~/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf with config:

   openssl_conf = openssl_init

   [openssl_init]
   ssl_conf = ssl_sect

   [ssl_sect]
   system_default = system_default_sect

   [system_default_sect]
   CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
2. Try curl with command:

   OPENSSL_CONF=~/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf curl -v https://yourwebsite.com
3. Assign system variable:

   export OPENSSL_CONF=~/.openssl_allow_tls1.0.cnf

   curl -v https://yourwebsite.com